# Will layover entry count as single entry?

Tags: transit, international-travel, layovers

Let's say I have a single-entry travel visa for a country, say Turkey, which is issued on August 1 and has one-month validity of entrance.
Now I book a return ticket to another country, say Egypt, from Aug 15-Aug20. It will lead to:
Origin->IST->CAI
CAI->IST->Origin

Will the entry on the IST on the first entry count as the single entry mandated by the visa to Turkey?

By the way, I have no plans to leave the airport on the first entry (Origin->IST->CAI).

Comment: Will the itinerary be issued on a single ticket? Will you be required to leave the sterile transit area for other reasons?

Comment: @xngtng Sorry, I didn't get it.

Comment: Sometimes, when you depart from country A and make a transit in another country B on a journey to yet another country C, you do not necessarily need to pass through the immigration checks (for example, see an immigration officer) because the transit area is secured (by airport security designs). In that case, your visa does not have to be used. Whether you can take advantage of this, however, depends on the airport, your airlines and your ticket. IST has the facility, but if you need to e.g. pick up your luggage, you will have to pass the immigration check (and use your visa).

Comment: To connect the dots: if you're traveling on a single ticket, then your airline will transfer your checked luggage from the first-leg plane (Origin > IST flight) to the second-leg plane (IST > CAI). If your luggage is transferred this way, then you do not need to pass Turkish immigration at IST, and you can remain in the transit area of the IST terminal. Doing that, you will not be using your visa because you will not be entering Turkey.

Answer (score 5):

> Will the entry on the IST on the first entry count as the single entry mandated by the visa to Turkey?

In most cases there will be no  entry into Turkey (or whatever country you are connecting in) at all. You stay in the international transit area without entering or leaving the connecting country. Exceptions are

1. This is booked as two seperate tickets
2. You are connecting in a country that doesn't support international transit (like the US or Canada)
3. The combination of your citizenship and transit country requires a transit Visa.
4. There is some other reason why you have to leave the international transit area. This is rare but can happen depending on the airlines, countries and airport layout involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any complete list of countries that don't support international transit? I tried to search but didn't find it.

Comment: @FailedScientist it's more important to look at the airport than at the country.  For example, in Germany there are a few airports that support it, but except for Frankfurt and Munich, they close overnight, so it's only possible if your departing flight leaves before the airport closes (i.e., it must be on the same day).  Other airports in Germany don't support it at all.  Canada also supports it in limited cases only.  This dependency on the specific details of the individual itinerary means that such a list would be of little value, which is probably why you're having trouble finding one.

Comment: @phoog In Istanbul you can definitely transit without going through Turkish immigration though (assuming single ticket etc).

Comment: @lambshaanxy that's certainly been my experience (though I haven't done it at every Istanbul airport).  Furthermore I am fairly certain that the main Istanbul airport does not close.  I really just wanted to address the request for a general worldwide list of where this is possible, especially since Turkey is presented in the question as a hypothetical example.